# Encoded JWT Token in SQL Database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to store my jwt token in the database, but I want it to be coded somehow.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiOWRiMTcwMmMtNDkyYy00MTJmLTkyM2QtM2Y5MWQyYzk0NTNjIiwicm9sZSI6IkNVU1RPTUVSX1JPTEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDU0NzM4NTcsImV4cCI6MTYwNTQ3NzQ1N30.o9nEeH4V7PZ61jWRG7-7epH79Vi9HJQWorvx5A37q4o
```

I can't use bcrypt because it has a 72 character limit. I am using NodeJS.

What other solution can I use?

Comment: if you mean "encrypted" - you can use nodes [crypto.createCipheriv](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options)

Comment: I'll repeat my comment from your other question: Why do you want to store jwt in the database? That sounds like you do not understand what JWTs are supposed to be used for.

Comment: because it's refresh jwt token. I store it in db every time the user logs in, because when logging in again, the token is overwritten and the first one does not work, so logout takes place. @luk2302